# Monitoring systems fans and temperatures

Tags: linux, debian, fan, temperature

I am trying to use GKrellM (http://members.dslextreme.com/users/billw/gkrellm/gkrellm.html) to monitor my system's fans/temperatures (I am trying to undervolt the fans a bit to make the systems quieter), but there don't seem to be any sensors available. I have lm_sensors installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try executing the `sudo sensors-detect` command in console.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use "fancontrol", not gkrellm. Gkrellm is a system monitor app. Fancontrol app comes with lm_sensors. AFAIK. Here (http://linux.die.net/man/8/fancontrol) is a manual. And you have to run "pwmconfig" with root to configure it up. The daemon will speed them down every time your PC boots up. Hope I was a bit of help..